# XNA Spritebatch sorting by texture vs depth

Tags: c#, xna

I am refining my 2D game engine, and I want to look in to sorting sprite batches by texture (because I'm quite often using the same textures repeatedly).

However, I also want to retain a few 'layers' of depth (i.e. ground < buildings < units < GUI etc).

My question is, which of the following is the best approach (in terms of performance)?

1. Create multiple SpriteBatches and Begin() and End() them in order; or...
2. Create a single SpriteBatch and call Begin() and End() multiple times, once for each layer (in order)?

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to have multiple `SpriteBatch` objects unless you are using them as a "sprite buffer" (a list of sprites to be drawn when `End` is called) and filling multiple buffers up at the same time.

If you are going in and out of begin/end blocks, you can reuse the `SpriteBatch` object (there is no saved state between blocks).

There's no major effect on performance. But multiple `SpriteBatch` objects will use more memory.

As you probably already know, `SpriteBatch` (in XNA 4.0) only batches sprites together (improving performance) if two or more sprites share the same texture and are drawn sequentially and within the same begin/end block (and if `Immediate` mode is not set). It sounds like both of your methods will produce the same batches - and thus no performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

You only need multiple `SpriteBatch`es if you like to have other settings for the new layer. So using the same `SpriteBatch` twice or more is just fine.

You could also consider using only a single batch if everything is the same. Just sort your sprites into buckets and draw them at the right time within the batch.

Comment: When you say 'draw them at the right time within the batch', do you mean all sprites between a single Begin() and End()? Wouldn't the Textured SpriteSortMode override whatever order I draw them in?

Comment: from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritesortmode - Deferred:"End will apply graphics device settings and draw all the sprites in one batch, in the same order calls to Draw were received"

Comment: But I'm using Texture sorting, not Deferred

Comment: Why not just throw a timer over the draw call and see how much time each technique costs?

Comment: One reason that won't work very well is due to the way buffering commands to the GPU works.